# Various ways to assign multiple columns to existing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have three lists of numerical values:

```
jac = [0.66,0.8,0.2,0.5,0.3]
sor = [0.8,0.8,0.2,0.5,0.7]
diff = [1,0.8,0.2,0.5,0.5]
```

and an existing pandas DataFrame (df):

```
   ham
0  0.5
1  0.6
2  0.6
3  0.7
4  0.9
```

The following is a solution

```
df.assign(diff=diffl).assign(sor=sor).assign(jac=jac)
```

What are the various ways to append these lists in one shot ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df.assign(diff=diffl, sor=sor, jac=jac)
```

Answer (score 3):

By using `pd.concat`

```
 A=[jac,sor,diff]

 pd.concat([DF,pd.DataFrame(A).T],axis=1).rename(columns={0:'jac',1:'sor',2:'diff'})

Out[2309]: 
   ham   jac  sor  diff
0  0.5  0.66  0.8   1.0
1  0.6  0.80  0.8   0.8
2  0.6  0.20  0.2   0.2
3  0.7  0.50  0.5   0.5
4  0.9  0.30  0.7   0.5
```